# How to make a join table search with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, entity-framework, linq

So I made a windows form which has a search textbox that will return the parts of string that you have entered in the datagrid. However, in my attempt to code this following event. The datagrid shows boolean instead.

Which parts of the code is making all these result turns boolean and how can i fix this?

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        this.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

        using (var context = new edeappEntities1())
        {
            var data = context.bookingorders
             .Join(
             context.addressbooks,
             booking => booking.addrID,
             address => address.addrID,
             (booking, address) => new
             {
                 accID = booking.accID.Contains(txtSearch.Text),
                 bookId = booking.bookingID.Contains(txtSearch.Text),

                 companyName = address.companyName.Contains(txtSearch.Text),

                 address = address.addressLn1.Contains(txtSearch.Text) || address.addressLn2.Contains(txtSearch.Text) ||
                 address.addressLn3.Contains(txtSearch.Text),

                 region = address.region.Contains(txtSearch.Text),
                 postcode = address.postcode.Contains(txtSearch.Text),
                 contact = address.contectName.Contains(txtSearch.Text),
                 phone = address.phoneNo.Contains(txtSearch.Text),
                 fax = address.faxNo.Contains(txtSearch.Text),
                 telex = address.telexNo.Contains(txtSearch.Text),

                 pickupTime = booking.pickupDate.Contains(txtSearch.Text)
                 || booking.pickupTime.Contains(txtSearch.Text)
             }
             ).ToList();

            foreach (var db in data)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(db.accID, db.bookId, db.companyName, db.address, db.region,
                     db.postcode, db.contact, db.phone, db.fax, db.telex, db.pickupTime);
            }
        }
    }
```

My modelling structure: [model1.edmx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oCmp.png)

Search result is boolean: [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/821611338542481429/852169513319268372/unknown.png)

Comment: Can you post the definition of the classes of both the entities?

Comment: What do you mean by the definition of the classes and how exactly I can show this to you?

Comment: For example `accID = booking.accID.Contains(txtSearch.Text)` this returns a `bool` *whether* the value `booking.accID` contains the match. What would you actually like here? Do you want all the data, but only where there is a match in one of those fields? Or do you want all data, but only return the each column where it contains a match otherwise null? Or do you want the same but with the index of the text?

Comment: @FurukawaHikaru Since you are using Entity Framework, both the database tables must be having a corresponding `address` and `booking` class which I was talking about. Anyway, I've figured out problem now, see my answer. Let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a Boolean result in all the columns because you are creating a new anonymous type and assigning the result of `string.Contains()` method to each property in that new anonymous type and `string.Contains()` returns a Boolean(`bool`).

For example, if I do this:

```
string str = "Hello!"
bool result = str.Contains("o");
```

Here, the `Contains()` method will return a Boolean value indicating whether the string contains the specified substring("o") in it. The return value here will be `true` which will be assigned to `result`.

In your code, you do something similar for each field:

```
accID = booking.accID.Contains(txtSearch.Text)
```

This will check if `booking.accID` contains the string searched by the user which is captured in `txtSearch.Text`. If your `booking.accID` contains `txtSearch.Text`, the method will return `true` and `false` if it does not contain the search text. This will create a new variable of type `bool` called `accId` and the return value will be stored in `accId` on the left-hand side of `=`.

---

#### Anonymous Types

In C#, an anonymous type is a quick way to create a wrapper object containing a set of properties without actually creating a class.

For instance, I want an object containing details about a person without creating a `Person` class, I can do this:

```
var myPerson = new { Name = "John", Age = 25, Salary = 10_000L };
```

Now, I have an object containing the properties `Name`, `Age` and `Salary` without even creating a `Person` class. The compiler creates a hidden class in the background. More on anonymous types [here](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/02/internals-of-anonymous-types.html).

You are creating a lambda function that returns an anonymous type as the fourth parameter of the `Join()` method. This lambda function will be called on each result of the join operation.

---

#### Solution

The filtering condition should be specified in a `Where()` method instead of assigning it to properties in the anonymous type. The anonymous type should be used to capture and combine the two results:

```
var searchData = context
.bookingorders
.Join(
    context.addressbooks,
    booking => booking.addrID,
    address => address.addrID,
    (booking, address) => new
    {
        Booking = booking,
        Address = address
    })
.Where(data => 
    data.Booking.bookingID.Contains(txtSearch.Text) ||  
    data.Address.companyName.Contains(txtSearch.Text) ||
    data.Address.addressLn1.Contains(txtSearch.Text) || 
    data.Address.addressLn2.Contains(txtSearch.Text) ||
    data.Address.region.Contains(txtSearch.Text) ||
    data.Address.postcode.Contains(txtSearch.Text) ||
    data.Address.contectName.Contains(txtSearch.Text) ||
    data.Address.phoneNo.Contains(txtSearch.Text) ||
    data.Address.faxNo.Contains(txtSearch.Text) ||
    data.Address.telexNo.Contains(txtSearch.Text) ||
    data.Booking.pickupDate.Contains(txtSearch.Text) || 
    data.Booking.pickupTime.Contains(txtSearch.Text)
)
.ToList();

foreach(var row in searchData)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(
        row.Booking.bookingId, 
        row.Address.companyName,
        $"{row.Address.addressLn1} {row.Address.addressLn2}", 
        row.Address.region, 
        row.Address.postcode,
        row.Address.contectName,
        row.Address.phoneNo,
        row.Address.faxNo,
        row.Address.telexNo,
        row.Booking.pickupDate,
        row.Booking.pickupTime
    );
}
```